# Play video when in viewport in React-Native using Skele Components

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

As a noob I am trying to create an app that plays videos (local videos) when in viewport. User scrolls left and right and when video is in view it autoplays. If the video is out of view it stops playing.

I tried following the following tutorial:
https://codedaily.io/courses/4/Fundamentals-of-React-Native-Video/37

Changed all the calculations to work with width instead of height but didn't work.

Then I stumbled upon Skele-Components:
https://blog.netcetera.com/viewport-aware-components-for-react-native-apps-a28ea605e89e

That checks if a component is in view or not. As a test I placed 2 videos inside my ScrollView. Scroll I console.logged "Entered" for when a video enters and "Left" for when the video leaves the viewport. The viewport clearly shows one video but the console logs 2 "Entered". Telling me the logic isn't working. Also the console doesn't show "Left" when video is scrolled out of view.

If you could take a look at the code and some help would be great.
thank you.

Below is the scrollview that contains the video source component.

```
export default class VideoScrollView extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Viewport.Tracker>
        <ScrollView
          horizontal={true}
          pagingEnabled={true}
          scrollEventThrottle={16}
        >
            <Ad source={Ad28} />
            <Ad source={Ad29} />
        </ScrollView>
      </Viewport.Tracker>
    );
  }
}
```

Below is the video component

```
const ViewportAwareVideo = Viewport.Aware(Video);

export class VideoAd extends Component {

  render() {
    this.state = {
      paused: true,
      visible: false
    };

    return (
      <View style={styles.viewContainer}>
        <ViewportAwareVideo
          source={this.props.source}
          paused={this.state.paused}
          style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
          innerRef={ref => (this.player = ref)}
          onViewportEnter={() => console.log("entered")}
          onViewportLeave={() => console.log("left")}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  viewContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using Skele version `1.0.0-alpha.40` or above. Viewport awareness for horizontal scroll views is not supported below that version. Here is a working Snack that can help you: https://snack.expo.io/@bevkoski/viewport-aware-lazy-loading-(horizontal).